# Libreoffice icon on xfce switcher

Tags: xubuntu, icons, libreoffice, xfce

I want to replace the ugly icons used for libreoffice on the xfce alt-tab switcher (Xubuntu 14.04), but I can't find it on any theme of icons neither any system folder. I really don't imagine where this icons are. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Which theme and symbols are you using? Terminal -> `xfce4-appearance-settings`. Normally the LibreOffice icons are colored.

Comment: Numix. But you give a hint, now I know this icons are from the internal Libreoffice theme that I use (sifr)...